# How to take ownership of a Pull Request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

### Background

A few months ago I started using graylog2 and championing its use within my company. Things have been going great and I read all the documentation I could find, with the (very little) time I am given.

Still, I managed to contribute to the project itself!
I found several wrongfully documented features and issues and I already made PR's ( that were accepted  by the organization ) to fix them in several of their projects!

Given my will to contribute, they have given me a chance to go from zero to hero - finish a Pull Request that was abandoned: https://github.com/Wizcorp/node-graylog2

### Problem

The problem here is that I don't know how to take ownership of an abandoned PR in github. 
According to what I read, there is no "pass ownership of this PR to someone else" feature.

I have asked for help but no one answered. 
I really want to take this chance and contribute to the community ( there are so many ways to help! ) but I have no idea on how to move forward.

### Question

Can someone help me and tell me how I can take ownsership of an abandoned Pull Request ?

Comment: Just take the code and create your own pull request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can:

- clone your fork
- add `Wizcorp` as a remote to https://github.com/Wizcorp/node-graylog2
- fetch `Wizcorp`: that will include the PR branch. See also "[Checking out pull requests locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/)"
- checkout your own PR branch to its HEAD
- rebase it on top of current master (in order to validate the current PR work when used with the most recent code)
- add your own commits to your PR branch (which includes the commits from the original PR)
- push and make a new PR from your pushed branch.

That is:

```
git clone https://github.com/<you>/node-graylog2 # your fork of node-graylog2
cd node-graylog2
git remote add Wizcorp https://github.com/Wizcorp/node-graylog2

# replace ID with the old PR ID
# for instance: 22 for https://github.com/Wizcorp/node-graylog2/pull/22

# replace BRANCHNAME by a name representing the theme of your PR
git fetch Wizcorp pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME 

git rebase master BRANCHNAME
# commit
git push -u origin BRANCHNAME
```

On GitHub, make a new PR from the branch you just pushed.
In other words, you don't take ownership of an old PR, you just make a new branch which will include the old PR commits plus your new ones.
You can write in the PR message that your work is based on the old PR.

Comment: Thanks, but I am having an issue. The command `git remote add https://github.com/Wizcorp/node-graylog2.git` doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe the correct command would be `git remote add --master https://github.com/Wizcorp/node-graylog2.git`, correct?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Sorry: it was `git remote add Wizcorp https://...`: the idea is to name the old repo with `Wizcorp` (but you could use any other name you want). I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't take ownership of the old PR. Take the branch name from the old PR and create a new PR to master / develop. You'll own this PR.

If that does not work for some reason, create a new branch from the branch of the old PR and now this branch will have the same changes as the old PR. You can raise a new PR from this newly created branch.

You said, this was for GitHub. I'd imagine the process is the same for other platforms.